# Kentcio v9 Smart Search Dialog with Results search mode localization

Tags: kentico

How can i localize the drop down option for the search mode? I did some digging and was able to adjust the localization for the search form labels but i'm at loss here.

The CMS Module SearchDialog.ascx call the drop down list here, but i can't see where the values come from.

```html
<cms:CMSDropDownList runat="server" ID="drpSearchMode" CssClass="DropDownField" />
```

Comment: It will help if you note which version of Kentico you are working with on these questions since the approach with often be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll make sure i add it as part of the subject line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the localization App and create resource strings for

- "srch.dialog.AllWords"
- "srch.dialog.AnyWord"
- "srch.dialog.anywordorsynonyms"
- "srch.dialog.ExactPhrase"

Believe those are the 4 you need.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find official documentation that helps much with this, though there have been articles in the past on older versions. However, one trick I've used previously is to look in the ~/CMSResources/cms.resx file, find the localized string there, and add a new one with the same key to the Localization module in Kentico. That is, add a new resource string in Kentico with the same key (the naming will be different depending on your version of Kentico).

Here's the docs discussing setting up a multilingual interface: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Setting+up+a+multilingual+user+interface

And here's a screenshot of the resx file: 
[image: Screenshot of .resx]

So in your case I'd create a new resource string within Kentico called "srch.dialog.allwords" as an example and that should overwrite and take priority over whatever is in the .resx file, plus you can manage it via the Kentico admin. There may be a quicker or more reliable way to view the list of default resource strings but in my recent installs of Kentico, the list is hidden from the admin interface.

Alternatively, of course, you could manage the resource strings via various .resx files as in the documentation, but I try to manage as much of these pieces via Kentico as possible for convenience.

Comment: I looked into physical .resx files, but also found it easier to use the built in 'app' for that. I'll look for the other strings in the cms.resx file.

Comment: Yes I agree, much easier to use the built in module, and finding the strings is sometimes tricky so starting in the .resx will hopefully help you find the strings you need to "override"